# How do you maintain pagination page number when redirecting after updating the edit page in CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm new to cakephp 3 and i want to maintain the pagination page number after updating the view page.

if i am in page 3 and i go to edit page and make changes and click submit button, i want to redirect to page 3.
currently it always go to page 1 after submitiong the edit confirmation button.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You will need to add the current page number into the edit link, and then look for that and modify where you redirect to at the end of your edit function.